# Weird characters are appearing while i move in blank spaces

Tags: filetype, plugin-devicons

When I exited Insert Mode I began to move around the file, these images began to appear. Does someone know how to fix it?

[image: Vim running]

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you launch vim with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: `001b` is the escape character. There is probably something in your vimrc or a plugin that sends this. See: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).